# Define catchment boundaries with GIS using R

Tags: r, hydrology

Using a DEM, I want to define catchment boundaries for a given location on a river. Basically, what area drains into this point. In ArcMap, I can do that with flowacc and other tools; but I'd like to do that in R.
I know how to import a DEM raster in R but that's about it.

Answer (score 1):

You can do that by using the GRASS package for R: [rgrass7](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/rgrass7/index.html)

The procedure is decribed in the `r.water.outlet` man page ([link](https://grass.osgeo.org/grass74/manuals/r.water.outlet.html))

Answer (score 1):

To complete @Marco's answer, watershed can be done in GRASS through `RQGIS3` or done in `RSAGA`.  Of course, you need QGIS, GRASS and SAGA installed on your computer.

Here is an example.  The DEM comes from :  http://ftp.geogratis.gc.ca/pub/nrcan_rncan/elevation/cdem_mnec/021/

### GRASS (through `RQGIS3`)

```
library(gdalUtils)
library(RQGIS3)
library(here)
set_env("C:/OSGeo4W64")
qgis_session_info()

gdal_translate(here("data", "cdem_dem_021M.tif"),
               here("temp_files", "dem_temp.tif"),
               projwin = c(-71.2, 47.5, -70.5, 47))
#get_usage(alg = "grass7:r.watershed")
run_qgis(alg = "grass7:r.watershed",
         elevation = here("temp_files", "dem_temp.tif"),
         threshold = 5000,
         drainage = here("temp_files/drain.tif"))
#get_usage(alg = "grass7:r.water.outlet")
bassin_grass <- run_qgis(alg = "grass7:r.water.outlet",
                         input = here("temp_files/drain.tif"),
                         output = here("temp_files/bassin_grass.tif"),
                         coordinates="-70.8837037458,47.0692354224",
                         load_output = TRUE)
```

produces:
[image]

### SAGA (through `RSAGA`)

If you're not satisfied with GRASS, do:

```
library(RSAGA)
rsaga.fill.sinks(in.dem = here("temp_files", "dem_temp.tif"), 
                 out.dem = here("temp_files", "no.sink.sgrd"),
                 out.wshed = here("temp_files", "bassin_saga.sgrd"),
                 method = "wang.liu.2006")
bassin_saga <- raster(here("temp_files", "bassin_saga.sdat"))
bassin_saga[bassin_saga!=1307] <- NA
```

which produces:

[image]