# Get catchment area of a lake polygon in R

Tags: r, polygon, dem, hydrology, catchment

I have several DEMs as geotiff files which I load into R using `raster::raster`. Additionally, I have lake outlines (located within the DEMs) in the form of shapefiles which I load into R using `raster::shapefile`.

What I would like to do is to identify the catchment of the lake within the DEM. Importantly, I would like to do this without making use of GIS tools (RGRASS, RSAGA, RQGIS), only R.

One approach I came up with involves the `topmodel::subcatch` function. This function allows me to get the catchment of any pixel in the raster. Therefore, I could use it to get the catchments of all the pixels which are within the lake polygon, or all the boundary pixels of the lake, alternatively.

However, since `topmodel::subcatch` only allows for a single pixel as input, I would have to perform it for all the lake boundary pixels and subsequently aggregate all the catchments. This seems inefficient. Is there a better way to do this (i.e. an R function similar to `topmodel::subcatch` which allows for multiple pixels, or a lake outline, as input)?

[This](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/303786/define-catchment-boundaries-with-gis-using-r) approach would solve the problem, yet it uses R GIS tools, which I don't have access to.

Comment: Thought - if you replace the flat surface of the lake with a depression with a single point minimum, then the catchment of that single point must also be the catchment of the entire lake... I'm not entirely sure how you'd do that though. You could create internal buffers but that could create multiple minima... Hmmm... Normally hydrologists try to get rid of pits - in this case you want to create one...

Comment: Thanks for the comment. Yes, this is a possibility. I actually have the bathymetries of the lakes. Do you think it would work if I extracted all the local minima of the bathymetries, create the catchments of those and then merge them?

Comment: Possibly, try it on a simple example.

Comment: Of course a workaround could be to do a sink-filling of the DEM to get slightly sloping lake surfaces (with topmodel::sinkfill for instance). Then identify the lowest pixel lying within the lake polygon (which is the lake outlet pixel) and compute the catchment from there.